# Grunt build does not seem to be including ui-router

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, angular-ui-router, bower

I've tried this a few different ways now but I've installed angular-ui-router with bower using the following command:

> bower install angular-ui-router

Awesome, so I can see that there is an angular-ui-router folder in my bower_components directory.  I can also see it listed as a dependency in bower.json

I included the path in my project like so

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

Running grunt serve, everything works perfectly.  All of my bower components load and ui-router is routing.

Running grunt build, the build succeeds.  But hosting the site, it seems that ui-router was not included.  I get this all too familiar error

> Module 'ui.router' is not available!

After poking around with grunt configs and a few other things, my last ditch effort was to stick a CDN script tag in my project

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

However, I get the same errors as above after running grunt build.

Is there some special trick to including ui-router?  All other bower components seem to be included just fine.

Comment: What is your grunt build task doing? How does it, package dependencies. Also, I see, you've not saved angular-ui-router.
`bower install angular-ui-router --save`

May be, the task process is using gulp wiredep and you've manually added angular-ui-router in your html file.

Comment: I'm using the default build task that is included with the yeoman angular generator: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular.  It does cdnify, uglify, and a bunch of fun things like that.  I'm a little new to this toolset so sorry if I'm not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just saw that ui-router doesnt have the 'main' entry in package.json. I didnt have time to poke more. But, in `bower.json` file. You can add `overrides` entry so that it adds the file in packaging dependency.

```
"overrides": {
  "angular-ui-router": {
    "main": [
      "release/angular-ui-router.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm not too sure, about the path. You can check your angular-ui folder to be sure. Also, dont point to the minified file, as uglify will run minification on your files.